# Chefspec Stubbing out Win32::Service on Linux

Tags: linux, winapi, chef-infra, chefspec

Our cookbook is used on both Linux and Windows machines, and when it runs/converges, the code runs perfectly on both types of systems. However the **rake unit** test fails on Linux. In my recipe I have:

```
service 'MyService' do
  action %i[enable start]
  only_if { ::Win32::Service.exists?("MyService") }
  not_if { ::File.exist?("#{install_dir}\\scripts\\instance-stopped") }
end
```

The error we are getting is:

> Failures:
>
> 1. perfagent::install_windows When set to install agent on Windows
>    converges successfully
>    Failure/Error: expect { chef_run }.to_not raise_error
>
>    expected no Exception, got #<NameError: uninitialized constant Win32> with backtrace:
>    # /tmp/chefspec20200924-2530-350e0zfile_cache_path/cookbooks/perfagent/resources/install_agent.rb:83:in
>    `block (3 levels) in class_from_file'

Is it possible, for just Linux systems, to dummy out the value in my spec file for the "only_if" above so that my rake unit test succeeds whenever we run the rakes on Linux?

---

Update:

As the cookbook is executed on both Linux and Windows systems, we have a check early in the execution of the cookbook such as:

```
if node['platform_family'] == 'windows'
  include_recipe 'cookbook::install_windows'
elsif node['platform_family'] == 'rhel'
  include_recipe 'cookbook::install_linux'
else
  log "This OS family (#{node['platform_family']})  is not supported" do
    level :info
  end
end
```

This means that the cookbook only calls the relevant recipes depending on platform_family. However, when we run rake unit on Linux we get the above error and on Windows the rake succeeds.

I've tried adding:

```
allow(::Win32::Service).to receive(:exists?).with(windows_service[:name]).and_return(true)
```

to the spec file, but this still fails on Linux and causes the Windows rake unit to fail too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of nested classes the stubbing is a little bit more complex. You also need to stub the class itself. Use `stub_const` [from the RSpec for that](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/mutating-constants):

```rb
let :subject do
  fake_win32 = Class.new
  stub_const('Win32::Service', fake_win32)
  allow(fake_win32).to receive(:exists?).and_return false
  ChefSpec::Runner.new(platform: 'windows', version: '2008R2').converge described_recipe
end
```

Comment: Fantastic. Works perfectly. The rake unit now succeeds on both Linux and Windows. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `if` conditions inside Chef resources. I am not sure it looks elegant to use conditionals for guards like `only_if` or `not_if` (themselves conditionals).

But you could do something like below:

```rb
service 'MyService' do
  action %i[enable start]
  if node['platform'] == 'windows'
    only_if { ::Win32::Service.exists?("MyService") }
  end
  not_if { ::File.exist?("#{install_dir}\\scripts\\instance-stopped") }
end
```

If your OS platform is `windows` only then the `only_if` guard will be checked.

---

Update:

Other option is to set the name of the service according to platform and get rid of `only_if` guard. Something like this:

```rb
# Set the service name appropriate to platform
svc_name = case node['platform']
when 'windows'
  'MyService'
when 'linux'
  'my-service'
end

# Then use the service name that was set:
service svc_name do
  action [ :enable, :start ]
  not_if { ::File.exist?("#{install_dir}\\scripts\\instance-stopped") }
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately I had already tried that, and I get the same error ... :(

Comment: The other option is to set the service name beforehand depending on platform and use that name in `service <name> do`.

Comment: Added an update to give an insight into how the cookbook runs the recipe in question. Also tried to add "allow(Win32::Service).to receive(:exists?).with(windows_service[:name]).and_return(true)" to the spec file, but this still fails on Linux.